# Chrome mouseover inspect window does not use toString()

Tags: google-chrome, debugging, variables, google-chrome-devtools, tostring

When mousing over a variable in chrome, I want to get a quick overview of any object without using console.log all the time in order to save time. How do I make chrome use toString() in this case?

[image]